# Getting URL data from Firebase into WebView in Android

Tags: android, firebase, webview, firebase-realtime-database, android-webview

I have implemented a **WebView** within my application and I am using **Firebase** as a Database, I want to show a **webPage** in webView by adding the **URL** of that webPage in Firebase database and fetching it from there, I have implemented all the things but my WebView is showing nothing when I open my application.Please help, I have searched many questions but they did not fulfill  my needs.

> I am using Android Studio

**webView class file:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_page);
        mdataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("weber");
        webviewthis = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView_news);
        webviewthis.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webviewthis.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webviewthis.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mdataRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             post2web webViewPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(post2web.class);
            webviewthis.loadUrl(webViewPost);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**webView xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView_news"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Getter and setter class :**

```
public class post2web {
    private String webViewPost;


    public post2web(){
    }

    public post2web(String webViewPost) {
        this.webViewPost = webViewPost;
    }


    public String getWebViewPost() {
        return webViewPost;
    }

    public void setWebViewPost(String webViewPost) {
        this.webViewPost = webViewPost;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to load any url at all, without querying Firebase?  Also, you're showing the class `post2web` but you're not using it anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: Try to get the error if any through this code [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) in the `setWebViewClient()`  Also check if you have included internet permission in manifest and that you are actually getting any data from firebase or not.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson how can i get data from firebase to show in webView?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes sir i am able to load URL without firebase quering and also i am updating my code by using post2web, please check.

Comment: @Alex Mamo sir please check this and help me.